# How do I change lots of Bootstrap column widths at once via a variable (or something better)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to be able to change all the 3's quickly into whatever number I need. (I have separate CSS I haven't included here, but please let me know if I need to add it.)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12 hero imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 rock imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pumpkin imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 soup imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 building imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 island imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 banana imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 beetle imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 chain imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 twigs imgProperties"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 petals imgProperties"></div>
</div>
```

I've tried setting up a variable two different ways, locally and globally. (I suspect I should be making this local, not global, but please correct me if I'm wrong)

Locally -

```
--elementColumns: 3;
```

And globally -

```
    :root {
  --elementColumns: 6;
}
```

And in both cases, calling for it like this:

```
    <div class="col-md-(var(--elementColumns)) rock imgProperties"></div>
```

But none of that is working. It just makes that one element not show up on the page.

How do I do this correctly? Is there a better way to change lots of Bootstrap column widths at once?  (If I can do this via CSS alone, I would prefer it, but JS solutions would be appreciated too.)

Answer (score 0):

1.) You are missing the a wrapper with the `row` class. In bootstrap, *columns* need to be wrapped inside *rows*.

2.) You are mixing CSS and HTML here.

`--elementColumns: 3;`
is a CSS variable definition. Once defined, either locally or globally, you may use this variable in other CSS slectors, or even in inline `style` attributes.

```css
:root {
  --elementColumns: 3;
}

/* you can then change the number of columns on a breakpoint */
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) {
  :root {
    --elementColumns: 6;
  }
}

/* selector is repeated here to be more specific then bootstrap's original .row > * selector */
.col-var.col-var {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: calc(100% / var(--elementColumns, 1));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 hero imgProperties">Hero</div>
    <div class="col-var rock imgProperties">1</div>
    <div class="col-var pumpkin imgProperties">2</div>
    <div class="col-var soup imgProperties">3</div>
    <div class="col-var building imgProperties">4</div>
    <div class="col-var island imgProperties">5</div>
    <div class="col-var banana imgProperties">6</div>
    <div class="col-var beetle imgProperties">7</div>
    <div class="col-var chain imgProperties">8</div>
    <div class="col-var twigs imgProperties">9</div>
    <div class="col-var petals imgProperties">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

- What are you trying to achieve with this variable?
- Do you want to change it based on screen width?
  Usually this is what the `col-md-*` and `col-lg-*` classes are for
- Are you looking for an easy way to update all columns if the design requirements change?
  Your IDE can do that with search and replace or bulk editing

Comment: 1,2) I'm working with Brilliant Directories widgets, so in this case, I think the row thing is already done for me (and the HTML box supports HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP, but I imagine it's still best to keep them separate.)

Comment: The first dash in ":root { --elementColumns" etc. is throwing an error in both places: "Expected RBRACE at line 2, col 3" (and line 8, col 5).

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't working. The "col-var" doesn't seem to be functioning. "col-md-var" doesn't work either. Was I supposed to replace my code with it outright, or edit it in some way?

Comment: And yes - I was looking for an easy way to update all columns if the design requirements change. I know I can find and replace, but as I learn I'm trying to figure out how to make my code as non-repetitive as possible.

Comment: the CSS code should go into your CSS file or a [<style>-Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp).
`col-var` is a new css class I invented. You can rename it (in both CSS and HTML) to your liking. `col-md-var` does not exist

Comment: Yes, while using a CSS variable for design decisions _can_ be done, I advise against it. It increases the code complexity (complex code = unmaintainable code), whilst being of no immediate benefit. Since you already chose bootstrap as your design system, I recommend you use the provided `col-md-*` classes and just update them (search/replace, bulk editing) when requirements change. A little bit of repetition is totally ok in a case like that.